# Image Map Coordinates Hover with ajax not working

Tags: php, html, css, ajax, imagemap

I'm having an image map with ajax hover to retrieve information from database table major_occurrence. But it's seems not working at all with the ajax call.

The hover is clickable so that it will redirect to another `doRpMap.php` showing the occurrence details.
Please advise on this matter. Thanks. *Pardon me being a programming newbie.

Am I doing the correct way for:

1. the variable to call back `getOccCount.php` `$result` in my Main Page?
2. how to insert the ajax call() into my `<span>`?

### getOccCount.php

```
<?php
$location_id = $_GET['location_id'];
$query = "SELECT COUNT(occurrence_id) FROM major_occurrence WHERE  '$location_id' = location_id GROUP BY location_id";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result    
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

### Main page

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:950px;
        height:1211px;
        background:url(images/Campus-Map.jpg);
        background-size: 950px 1211px;
        font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:8pt;
    }

    #map li {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }

    #map li a {
        position:absolute;
        display:block;
        background:url(blank.gif);
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000;
    }

    #map li a span { display:none; }

    #map li a:hover span {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:200px;
        left:20px;
        top:20px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        background:#fff;
        padding:5px;
        filter:alpha(opacity=80);
        opacity:0.8;
    }

    #map a.rpc{
        top: 1060px ;
        left: 585px;
        width: 78px;
        height: 65px;
    }
</style>
<body>
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#map span').hover(function () {
                var $t = $(this);
                var location_id = $t.attr("location_id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getOccCount.php',
                    data: "{location_id: location_id}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (result) {
                        $t.html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result[0]);
                    }
                }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <ul id="map">
            <li><a class="rpc" href="doRPMap.php?location_id=1"><span location_id="1"><b>RPC</b></span></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete solution will require some work. Let me give you a few ideas.  I apologize for having trouble with formatting ... the {} function here doesn't seem to work properly for me.

1. As you stated, you want to query the number of incidents for a given location. In your `getOccCount.php` I don't see any mechanism of passing a location id. It appears that the query always returns *ALL* occurrences. You probably want to add a line similar to

   `$location_id = @$_REQUEST['location_id'];`

   and use that value in a WHERE clause in your query.
2. The `<span>` you have in your html doesn't have a location_id attribute:

   `<span><b>RPC</b></span>`

   So the line where you try to retrieve that attribute will not find anything:

   `var location_id = $(this).attr("location_id");`
3. You're doing the same ajax call twice, in two different ways. The whole block starting with `$.ajax({` makes a call to `getOccCount.php`, however, I don't see you doing anything with the `data` passed to the success callback.
   Then again in the success callback function you write `$.get("getOccCount.php", ...` which essentially does the same call again. This time you're trying to pass the `location_id` parameter, which we already know is not looked at in `getOccCount.php`.
4. Where you are trying to store the result back in the `span` that the user hovered over you use `$('#map>span')` as a selector which will store the result in *ALL* spans.

So, a start to your solution could look like this:

```
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#map span').hover(function () {
        var $t = $(this);
        var location_id = $t.attr("location_id");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getOccCount.php',
            data: "{location_id: location_id}",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {
                $t.html('Total Number of Occurrence: ' + result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<ul id="map">
    <li><a class="rpc" href="doRPMap.php?locID=1"><span location_id="1"><b>RPC</b></span></a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Like I said, a full solution will require more work, especially on passing the location_id into your query. Hope that my ideas will help make progress.

Comment: As per advised, i've made changes to my exisiting codes but it still can't seem to work. The map is still showing hover popup with just the text "RPC" without any ajax call.. Thanks for advising.

Comment: Since you're using jquery in your script, can you verify that the jquery files are getting included?

Comment: Yes. Of course. I've included into my script. <?php (include 'navBar.php'); ?> ajax do not need any script right..

Comment: ok I fixed 3 errors in my sample script.  1. The whole script needs to be called inside the `$(document).ready()` function.  2. `t.attr` should be `$t.attr`.  3. there was a mismatched ending brace on the success function (removed `);` ). I suggest to either use a javascript debugger or put an alert as the first line into the `hover` function to see whether it is being called.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. Made changes again not working. Thanks.

Comment: OK. Two more things. 1. The `method` in the ajax call needs to be put in quotes: `'GET'`.  2. Your selector `#map>span` is wrong because it selects only `<span>` tags that are direct children of `#map`. However, they are inside a `<li>` and `<a>` tag. Use the `ancestor descendant` selector instead: `'#map span'` (with a `space`).

Comment: Yes. Tried. Sorry still not working. Btw Thanks for your hardwork. Pardon me for such newbie.

Comment: Well, I got the ajax call firing in my test environment. If you put an alert as the first statement into the hover function and it's not firing, then I assume you're not loading jquery correctly. You should have some line in your page that looks like this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Yes. i definitely have this script source inside my navBar.php <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> and it's encoded inside my main page. as<?php (include 'navBar.php'); ?>

Comment: Or would you mind showing me some working example like jsfiddle demo of your test environment.. Thanks.